# Resource not found: res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-resources

I recently released my first app. Having only tested in SDK emulator and on a Galaxy S2, the feedback about devices it works on coming to me has been great.

Unfortunately I've had a couple users report FCs to me. The common factor between them is that they are both MIUI users (different devices IIRC).

One has been very helpful in providing info and trying out sample builds to resolve the issue but I just can't seem to make any headway on it.

I've searched online fairly extensively. Although I've found people with similar reports, I've had nothing that helps solve this particular case that I can see.

**Problem+notes:**

- the issue seems to be that `res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml` doesn't exist
- I've made no custom resources for list backgrounds, nor am I making any reference to this particular resource in my code
- I'm using ActionBarSherlock (`minSdkVersion == 7`, `targetSdkVersion == 7`, `project build target == 15`)
- the crash occurs when loading a preference activity (which does have `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog"` in the manifest)
- the crash **does not** occur when loading another preference activity via the same method (starting an intent with the activity class)

**For reference:**

- [the original bug report](http://pastebin.com/269v1qFG), and
- [their logcat output](http://pastebin.com/FSwtLDuJ)

The thing that confuses me the most about this is that the particular settings I'm displaying in this preference activity would work when it was a sub-`<PreferenceScreen>` in the original preferences XML (I split the preferences lists apart as it was more user friendly).

**Edit:** It should be noted that this is an empty `<PreferenceScreen>` which gets filled out via code; it still worked when it was in a single `PreferenceActivity`.

Here's how I'm starting the preference activity which works:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And here's how I'm starting the preference activity which fails:

```
Intent subredditsIntent = new Intent(MainTabs.this, SubredditPreferencesActivity.class);
startActivity(subredditsIntent);
```

**I've just noticed I'm using `MainTabs.this` in the second one**, probably due to copying it from a nested dialog class; surely this is not the cause as it crashes when invoked from the dialog as well?

This seems to be limited to MIUI devices, but I can't confirm that with 100% certainty. Has anyone else experienced this at all?

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks

- D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a "last grasp" build out to the helpful MIUI user. The only change I made was  to remove `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog"` from the activity definition i the Manifest.

This seemed to work!

For reference for other people, it seems (at this time) that using the dialog theme for a preference activity causes FCs under MIUI.

I haven't yet tested if setting the theme manually via the `onCreate()` method ends up FCing.

Hope this helps someone!