# Navigation Drawer not working on pre-ICS versions

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented Navigation Drawer based on a ListView. It works perfectly fine with ICS and above versions of Android. However, on older versions, it crashes with this error:

```
06-23 15:50:11.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
File res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml 
from xml type drawable resource ID #0x0
```

I have tried copying this particular xml file from Android sdk to my own project, but that didn't help.

Here's the xml file(abridged):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the code:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

The complete stack trace:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
android.view.InflateException: 
    Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1521)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:320)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
    ... 35 more

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
    File res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1693)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:326)
    ... 39 more

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
    File res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml 
    from xml type drawable resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1920)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1688)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: And how do we guess your code?

Comment: @Waza_Be, my code does nothing special. Not at least anything that would effect the error status. It is just a simple ListView with no modifications and pretty basic Navigation Drawer. However, if others think too that code is important, I would do it gladly.

Comment: a simple ListView with no modifications and pretty basic Navigation Drawer never crash with such an error, you MUST have something wrong somewhere and if you want people to help, you cannot say: my app crash, but code is fine, help me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324834/resource-not-found-res-drawable-list-selector-background-xml

Comment: But if I remove the theme, app crashes saying something like "Your application must apply one of ActionBarSherlock themes..."

Comment: What theme are you using????? I really would like to help, but don't seem to want to give onformations

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, if it seems so. Here's how I apply theme <application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >. I have also tried to summarize the code above. Please have a look.

Comment: Please paste the entire stack trace.

Comment: This should not have anything to do with the drawer itself. As Waza_Be indicated, something's a bit off with your themes, or possibly with the row layout you are using for the `ListView` inside of the drawer.

Comment: There are other ListView's in app that work fine. However, when I enable code related to this particular ListView(/Drawer) the app starts crashing. Another hint is, until I added Drawer, the app was working perfectly fine on pre-ICS versions.

Comment: Solved! Thanks @CommanWare for the hint. Answer coming soon.

Comment: Have you got the answer(Running navigation on pre-ICS)? I am running with same problem, I have tried with the solution given by You, but no success. please share the solution if found.

Comment: @Bashir The answer I posted below works fine for me. Just to confirm, are you getting exact same error as I was getting(given in log above)?

Comment: @deej Thanx dear I got the answer, The problem was caused by android:layout_gravity="start" Tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official Google example for Navigation drawer, gives this TextView as part of drawer_list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

However, with these exact three values of attributes, the application fails on pre-ICS android OSes. I verified by giving my own custom values(anything different from these) and it works like magic on every version.

Answer (score 8):

The official [Navigation drawer example](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip)  has a minimum API-level of 14. In case this minimum is set to an ICS-version (for example 11) this will result in a forced close as method setHomeButton is only avaible as of API-14.

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

When commenting out the previous statement this results in inflate exception which is a result of using adroid dimensions which are also added in API-14.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
      android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
      android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

For my app in which I support API-11+ I have solved this as follows.

1) In drawer_list_item.xml refer to custom attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/myapp_activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?attr/myapp_listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/myapp_textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
```

2) In values/attrs.xml define your custom attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="Theme">

    <!-- Attributes below are needed to support the navigation drawer on Android 3.x. -->
    <!-- A smaller, sleeker list item height. -->
    <attr name="myapp_listPreferredItemHeightSmall" format="dimension" />

    <!-- Drawable used as a background for activated items. -->
    <attr name="myapp_activatedBackgroundIndicator" format="reference" />

    <!-- The preferred TextAppearance for the primary text of small list items. -->
    <attr name="myapp_textAppearanceListItemSmall" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

3) In values-11/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces -->
    <!-- AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices. -->
      <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

          <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->


          <!-- Implementation of attributes needed for the navigation drawer as the default implementation is based on API-14. -->
          <item name="myapp_listPreferredItemHeightSmall">48dip</item>
          <item name="myapp_textAppearanceListItemSmall">@style/MyappDrawerMenu</item>
          <item name="myapp_activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/ab_transparent_action_bar</item>
      </style>

      <style name="MyappDrawerMenu">
          <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
          <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
      </style>

</resources>
```

4) In values-v14/styles.xml

```
   <resources>

       <!-- Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces -->
       <!-- AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and -->
       <!-- res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices. -->

       <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

           <!-- For API-14 and above the default implementation of the navigation drawer menu is used. Below APU-14 a custom implementation is used. -->
           <item name="myapp_listPreferredItemHeightSmall">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
           <item name="myapp_textAppearanceListItemSmall">?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall</item>
           <item name="myapp_activatedBackgroundIndicator">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
       </style>

   </resources>
```

In case you want to support older/other versions, you will need to add a styles.xml for that specific version.

Comment: cool solution! How did you implement ab_transparent_action_bar? I try copying something out of the original ressources, but it fails :)