# InflateException when using custom xml attribute

Tags: android, xml, textview, layout-inflater

I am currently setting up a navigation drawer in my android app. Therefore I used the trick described in the second answer from this post to get cross-platform compatible attributes: [Navigation Drawer not working on pre-ICS versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261230/navigation-drawer-not-working-on-pre-ics-versions)

It all worked fine when I just used a single TextView in my layout file (as done in the example from the post)

However, when I placed the TextView inside a RelativeLayout i got an InflateException like this:

```
08-08 22:13:01.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3514): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

I then removed the three lines that contained a custom xml attribute and it worked again.

Can anyone tell me why on earth this happens? Why is it not working when I place the TextView in another container (like my RelativeLayout)?

EDIT: This is the RelativeLayout that I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
    android:src="@drawable/icn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/myapp_textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:minHeight="?attr/myapp_listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/text1_color"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/text2_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text2_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the xml for us to debug

Comment: Post your xml and your java class please.

Comment: added the xml file to the question